# How do I refresh an APIKit project from the RAML?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

How do I force Anypoint Studio to refresh the autogenerated APIKit code from the given RAML? I want to make minor changes to the RAML and don't want to regenerate the whole project each time.

Comment: This question was raised a while back on the [Mulesoft forum](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/3034/apikit_possibility_to_update_flow_from_changed_raml_file.html) and it seems there's no solution for it - not sure if any updates have been made between now and the latest comment on that thread though. Would be interested to know the answer if there is one...

Comment: This helped, they mention the option I was looking for in that thread, right click the RAML and go to Mule>Generate Flows. Still not working for me but I think it's a problem with my RAML so case closed.

Answer (score -1):

You can test your RAML at https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/ 
If you are making any changes in the RAML, then check it here only. You can edit there & test.On the right side, there is console for testing your RAML. there is a option called 'try it'.

Comment: Thanks, not what I was asking though. I was trying to regenerate the mule flows from the RAML, see the comments above.